# Glimpse screen takes up the whole page. How to resize it?

Tags: glimpse

I have an irritating problem with Glimpse.
I wanted to see everything I can on a Glimpse tab so I maximised it's size on the page.
Now I cannot resize it back again. There is no edge I can drag down. I am sure there is a simple way of sorting this. I tried switching off Glimpse, but when I switched it back on again it was taking up the whole screen again. I don't want to install and uninstall, so how do I fix this easily?
I am using ie10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way of fixing this, which is to go into Developer Tools and change the css settings dynamically by using the CSS top class, replacing another class like margin, and putting in 200px and then resizing from that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is launch the Glimpse as Standalone tool.